# client UDP payload creation using go

Tags: go

I am new to golang and client-server UDP communication. I just started with goLang yesterday. I would highly appreciate guidance from the members of this group. I am trying to write client code to send a request to the server. I get to know the following line of code will send the request packet to the server. However, I want to know that in the below code if I want to send a request message which is something like:

1. MessageId (4 bytes IP address + 2 Bytes port number + 2 bytes random number + 8 bytes time at which request sent)
2. Application payload
3. checksum

I could feel it must be a very basic question but having no background in it is making me feel stuck. My question is how to create (concatenate) different bytes to form MessageId.

I apologize for any inconvenience.
Thanks

```
conn, err:= net.Dial("udp", nil, serverIPaddress:port)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
}
log.Printf("Established connection to %s \n", service)
defer conn.Close()

message := []byte("Hello UDP server!")

         _, err = conn.Write(message)

         if err != nil {
                 log.Println(err)
         }
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, your question is: how can you send a "request" containing your MessageId, payload and checksum, rather than the "Hello UDP server!" string you are sending now..? When you write to the connection, it's just a bunch of bytes going over the wire. You will need to encode/serialise your data somehow in a format common to the client and server. Unless you have a good reason not to, you should probably go with some well-known format like JSON, XML or protocol buffers. Go has good support for all of these (with JSON and XML in the standard library, even)

Comment: Thanks, your reply helps me to connect bits and pieces I explored from the internet.  I still need to understand that I will give "MessageId, payload and checksum" as input to protocol buffer and it will produce an output of me in the form of byte array which I could use to write on the connection to the server?

Comment: That's right. Here's an example of how this could work with JSON: https://play.golang.org/p/AzqVNp-I8hl

Comment: one more follow up question: to create a request packet Message ID is defined as: the first 4 bytes are the client IP, the next 2 bytes are the port number, the next 2 bytes are randomly generated, and the last 8 bytes the time the request was generated (e.g., in nanoseconds). Alternatively, one could use UUIDs.